# Separating optimization algorithm from application

Tags: c#, windows, architecture, service, n-tier-architecture

I have just started doing my master thesis. My assignment is to create a system which optimizes the heating of apartments. The apartments have sensors that are measuring the current temperature.

By using these temperatures and some other measures an optimization is done and a signal is sent back to the apartments regulating the temperature. The optimization is to be done 24/7 in a circular manner looping through all the apartments.

The system therefore must communicate with the sensors, do an optimization and also log the data. Furthermore, a webb based user interfaces should be provided to the apartments so that they can see the current power/water consumtion.

The system will be written in C#/.Net.

I do not have must experience in building large-scale systems and have only limited experience with .Net. My initial thoughts about this is to have a N-tier architecture where, at the highest level two interfaces are provided. One web interface for the user and then some sort of interface for the sensors (which have the optimization algorithm below in the architecture).

[image: Preliminary architecture]

I would like to reuse as much of the components further down in the architecture as possible but with the limitation that I would like to seperate the optimization algorithm as much as possible from the rest. That is, a crasch in the algorithm should not affect the rest of the system (except perhaps the sensor interface).

So, my question is. In what way should I implement the optimization part? Should I create a windows service or should I let it run in an own thread?

If a windows service is a good choice, is it possible to use the components further down in the hierachy? That is, the database repository, all the objects etc.

Is the choice of architecture good. If not, why?

Is it something special I should think about when designing/implementing the system?

Note. It is not clear at this stage how the communication between the sensors and the system will be carried out.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, some comments about your approach. My recommendation for you is to build the system as simple as possible. Avoid n-tier thinking, services and other complex things -- until you need it. And then when you discover that you need it you can create it.

Focus on value adding things when you build your system. Don't begin creating reusable components and algorithms (that you later discover were not as reusable, or usable, that you first thought). Instead, start by solving a problem for the end user. Solve it in the simplest possible way. Then solve the next problem. Then analyze your code and see if you can find common parts that you can extract into reusable parts. Then repeat by solving another problem.

Try to solve as small problems as possible each time. When you've solved 10 or 20 problems you will discover that you have created or can create some kind of layering or componentization in some way.

Create the interface for the sensors by creating more than one sensor. When having only one sensor you can only guess what the interface should look like. With more sensors you will know.

Regarding the robustness (not crashing when calling a sensor) it depends on how robust you want it. A catch-all when invoking a method on the sensor, and thus executing the sensor code in the same process, would catch most problem and be the far most simple solution. I would definitely start with this. I wouldn't even execute it in a different thread unless you have the need for it (like for instance create a responsive UI).

Moving the sensor to it's own process (service) would let the operating system handle problems such as writing to bad memory. Such problems you typically don't encounter if the sensor is written i C# though.

If you choose to place the sensor code in a service it's still possible to reuse code. Just place the common code in an assembly that both processes can access.